# iPhone SDK: Retrieving street info while scrolling MapView

Tags: iphone, ios4, reverse-geocoding

Is it possible to continuously retrieve street name/house number (and update it somewhere in text box or callout) while user scrolls UIMapView?
I've found that MKReverseGeocoder is responsible for converting (latitude, longitude) into street name, but it is said that "you should not send more than one reverse-geocode request per minute".

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

As you've discovered, not really: you'll get rate limited pretty quickly. Both the standard Google Maps API and MKReverseGeocoder get rate limited on a per user basis. These limits are pretty high, but not high enough for you to continuously fire off requests.

There's nothing to stop you doing it, but chances are if you continuously abuse the reverse geocoder your app may get pulled, or reverse geocoding requests will simply fail until your rate limit is reset.